# Asp.Net MVC Execute Oracle PL/SQL Stored Procedure With Patrameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, plsql

I Want to execute oracle pl/sql stored procedure with parameters in asp.net MVC code first.

Here is My Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE sp_getuserhosps(p_city IN VARCHAR2,cnt OUT DECIMAL) 
AS
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO cnt FROM "PersonStatus" p1 
INNER JOIN HOSPITALS p2 ON P1."HospitalCode"=p2.KURUM_KODU
WHERE P2.IL_KODU=p_city AND p1."Statu"=1;

END;
```

This returns DBMS OUTPUT `CNT=135555` like this.

I tried Asp.Net MVC Code Like This:

```
var sql = "DECLARE cnt DECIMAL;BEGIN SP_GETUSERHOSPS(@p_city,cnt);END;";
var total = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, new OdbcParameter("@p_city","07"));
```

But there is no result from this.And returning as error like this:

> Cannot cast 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter' to 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'

How Can I Solve This?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error said you need to pass an instance of `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter` instead of `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter`.

So you'll have this:

```
var sql = "DECLARE cnt DECIMAL;BEGIN SP_GETUSERHOSPS(:p_city,cnt);END;";
var total = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, new OracleParameter(":p_city","07"));
```

Notice I replace '@' char with  ':' char. because parameter in Oracle are prefixed with the latter while '@' is use for SQL Server.

If you want to get the `cnt` value then rewrite your code like this:

```
var cntParameter = new OracleParameter("cnt", OracleDbType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
var cityParameter = new OracleParameter("p_city", OracleDbType.Number,  "07", ParameterDirection.Input);
var sql = "BEGIN SP_GETUSERHOSPS(:p_city,:cnt);END;";
var total = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, cityParameter, cntParameter );
// Here you check the cntParameter.Value to get cnt parameter value.
```

Comment: Ok Thanks.But at this time returning -1.But I need count (cnt).

Comment: @kodcu Then I edited my answer to show you how to get the output value even it is not the intial question.

Comment: Very nice answer.But this couldnt return count.Still it returns -1.Is it necessary to change stored procedure?

Comment: @kodcu What do you mean by return -1. Do you check the cntParameter.Value? You don't need to check the `total`variable.

Comment: you are awesome :) Very Thanks